# amsart title page formatting

Tags: titles, amsart

I'm new to tex stackexchange, so apologies in advance for anything stupid I do or say.

I'm trying to reformat the title page in the amsart class. Ideally I'd have something like this:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/university-assignment-title-page

I know the amsart class is fairly strict, so I realize this may not be possible/reasonable. If this is the case, I'd settle for

1. Being able to center the title, author, and date on the page (centered horizontally by default, would like centered vertically as well).
2. Being able to adjust the size and style (i.e. bold) of the title, author, and date individually.

I've found some code using etoolbox that puts the date with the title and author:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}
{\ifx\@empty\@date \else {\vskip3ex \centering\footnotesize\@date\par\vskip1ex}\fi 
\ifx\@empty\@dedicatory}
{}{}
\patchcmd{\@adminfootnotes}
{\ifx\@empty\@date\else \@footnotetext{\@setdate}\fi}
{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

I've never used etoolbox before, but it seems like I should be able to used it similarly to the code above to change the \maketitle command to at least do 1 and 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  regarding `amsart`, it really doesn't have a separate title page.  however, `amsbook` does, so i'll address that.  title pages of ams publications are created separately by the graphic arts group, so the title page defined in the document class is just a "place marker", to make the title and author obvious to someone picking up a stack of paper for copyediting.  so you are free to create your own design; just be careful not to redefine anything that might be needed later.

Answer (score 1):

`amsart` doesn't really have a separate title page, but you can create one
according to the style you need.  a few patches are needed, but this example
should get you started.

i've assumed that, in addition to the separate title page, you do want the
title and author "as usual" on the first page of the body.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewenvironment{titlepage}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{0}
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}
}{%
  \vspace{3\baselineskip}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \newpage
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\if@titlepage \newpage \else}
{\if@titlepage
 \vspace{\baselineskip}
 \else}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  {\Large The Title\par}
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  The Author\par
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \today
\end{titlepage}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\begin{abstract}
 The abstract.  Make it longer so that it fills more than one line.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
some text

\end{document}
```

without the patch to omit the `\newpage` from `\maketitle`, there will be a
page break (not wanted!) after the abstract.  also, for an unknown reason, the usual space between abstract and body text is suppressed, so i've
inserted a blank line.  this shouldn't have to happen; i'll add a note about
these adjustments to things that should be looked into when `amsart` is
overhauled (someday).

re centering material vertically on a page, it always looks out of balance
to me, so i've added a few extra blank lines on the title page before the
final `\vspace`; you can omit it (or change its height) as you wish.
for some reason that i can't